# Return an iterator after modification

Tags: python

I have an iterator `result` in one function and I need to return an iterator after making some changes to the objects in `result` from that function. I don't want to iterate over the `result` as it is causing performance degradation. I want to perform that operation on the fly for each item in the `result`.

This is the code which iterates over the result to do that operation.

```
sols = []
# Get rid of this loop
for sol in result:
    sols.append(dict((symbols[abs(lit) - 1], lit > 0) for lit in sol))
# Return iterator object
return (sol for sol in sols)
```

Comment: Have you tried `yield` keyword http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python

Comment: I agree with Mikko, yield would be a lot simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Just don't store the values in a `sols` list:

```
def f(result):
  return (dict((symbols[abs(lit) - 1], lit > 0) for lit in sol) for sol in result)
```

This yields (no pun intended) a generator which incrementally traverses the given `result` parameter.